# DataTypeAttribute and unobtrusive validation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I have MVC 5 project that uses unobtrusive validation:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

And here is my model class:

```
public class LoginModel {
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Problem address")]
    [Required]
    public string Mail { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

When I enter invalid value in Mail field I always get standard "Please enter a valid email address." which is hard-coded in `jquery.validate.js`. My `ErrorMessage` value is ignored. Why? Moreover, if I remove `ErrorMessage` parameter the standard message is not localized unlike the rest of validation attributes (Required, StringLength). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the DataType attribute is not validation, it is used for formatting data in views, choosing which type of input field to generate etc.

The error message comes from the validation attribute. Try:

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Problem address")]
public string Email{ get; set; }
```

Comment: If the purpose of the DataType attribute is not validation (as every thread on this topic states) why does using it add validation? I specifically used it to allow an "email" type html input, but along with it comes validation that I don't want.